# Поднять страницу на верх при обновлении

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть анимации на странице. Если листнуть до футера, а потом обновить - автоматом окажемся на футере и если листать на верх - криво анимации отображаются. Пробовал поднять на верх так, но не работает:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(window).scrollTop(0).delay(800);
});
```

Пробовал и без задержки. Совет "подключи jquery" не катит :)

Answer (score 1):

Это конечно не лучшее решение.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 100);
    });
```

Comment: @YaroskavZaika К сожалению, ваше решение не работает

Comment: @ivan-blohin ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: @higimo неа. Так и осталась эта проблема нерешенной

Comment: @ivan-blohin если бы вы описали что происходит или дополнили вопрос кодом, ссылкой на сайт, то мы бы могли помочь. Гадать в чём у вас проблема, когда вы сами не признаётесь, тут не принято.